# Next line should not execute if any errors occured

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.rename("newFile.txt", "sample.txt", (error) => {
    console.log("error")
})

console.log("success")
```

This is my code. If any error occurred during rename the file, the program will not go to next line.

But now I am getting success message if any error occurred also.

How to fix this issue. Please anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That happened because you have asynchronous function execution. It will execute the next statement without waiting for the current statement to finish. Hence, you usually get the `console.log("success")` being executed (unless the `error` is being returned earlier). To prevent that, do a check on the `error` and print whether it succeeded or not based on that. For example:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.rename("newFile.txt", "sample.txt", (error) => {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log("success")
    } else {
        console.log("error")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Following are the links you should look at:

1. [async programming](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html)
2. callbacks [link 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and [link 2](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/)

---

Following is the right way:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.rename('newFile.txt', 'sample.txt', error => {
  if (error) { // handle errors here
    console.log('error');
  } else { // it is success
    console.log('success');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of asynchronous function execution. If you want async execution, Andreas is correct. But if you want synchronous execution, use following code:

```
fs.renameSync("newFile.txt, "sample.txt");

console.log("success");
```

Comment: how to add callback function?

Comment: No callback is required. renameSync throws error in case of error, catch error to handle it. In case of success, execution move to next line.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should change as below:

```
fs.rename("newFile.txt", "sample.txt", (error) => {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log("error")
})
```